# Google Script Not Iterating Through Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script that changes the event dates to the day of the year, so 8/26/15 is 237, and also changes today's date to it's day of the year. It then compares the event date day of the year against today's date day of the year. If the event date integer is smaller than today's date integer than it changes the event description in the google calendar to Event Closed. The problem is it only does this for the first event in the spreadsheet. It does not iterate through all of the events and change all of the event descriptions that are before today's date.

```
function compareDates(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Events");
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var headerRow = 1;
    var i = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        var row = data[i];
        var room = row[5];
        var description = row[6];
        var agegroup = row[7];
        var registration = row[8];
        var calname = row[14];
        var registrants = row[17];
        var id = sheet.getRange(headerRow + 1, 16).getValues();
        var event = CalendarApp.getEventSeriesById(id);
        var description1 = (description + '\n' + '\n<b>Room:</b> ' + room + '\n' + '\n<b>Event Type:</b> ' + calname + '\n' + '\n<b>Age Group:</b> ' + agegroup);
        var today = parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new  Date(sheet.getRange("U2").getValues()), "EST", "D"));
        var eventDate = parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[0]), "EST", "D"));
        var testED = sheet.getRange(headerRow + i, 22).setValue(eventDate);//To see if var Today works.
        var testT = sheet.getRange(headerRow + i, 23).setValue(today);//To see if var eventDate works.
            if (today > eventDate && registration === 'Y') {
                var descriptionHTMLEC = '\n <div id="registration_button" ><a style="text-align:right;color:white!important;text-decoration:bold;background-color:rgb(121,183,138);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgb(221,75,57),rgb(121,183,138nnn ));color:#ffffff;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);border-radius:2px;display:inline-block;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;height:27px;line-height:27px;padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;white-space:nowrap;text-decoration:none;color:white" target="_blank">Event Closed</a>';
                var descriptionRegistrationEC = (description1 + '\n' + '\n' + descriptionHTMLEC);
                event.setDescription(descriptionRegistrationEC); 
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are modifying the same event on each iteration. The statement:

```
var id = sheet.getRange(headerRow + 1, 16).getValues();
```

Will assign the same value to `id` each time. Shouldn't it be:

```
var id = sheet.getRange(headerRow + i, 16).getValues();
```

For more readable code you can just the `getTime()` function on the date object.

```
 var today = new  Date(sheet.getRange("C2").getValues()).getTime();
 var eventDate = new Date(row[0]).getTime();
```

Comment: I initially had had headerRow + i..., it didn't work at all. I will try getTime(). Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so whats `var id = sheet.getRange(headerRo...).getValues()` suposed to return? Is it a value or an arrary?

Comment: It gets the event series id from the spreadsheet. Otherwise, the description of the event in Google Calendar won't be updated with Event Closed.

Comment: range.getValues() will return a two dimensional array ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues() ) . Hence to get one value you would call range.getValue() to get one cell. Or range.getValues()[0][0]

Comment: I tried the`'var today = new  Date(sheet.getRange("C2").getValues()).getTime();`
 `var eventDate = new Date(row[0]).getTime();`. It only it did it for the first event, not all of the ones that are in the past.